# Setting event date as "preferred" in Gramps

Tags: gramps

In Gramps, if I have three different sources stating three different years for the same person's birth year, is there a way to identify one of those dates / sources as "preferred", while keeping all three dates / sources attached to the person?

Answer (score 4):

In Gramps you can create a custom event type.
I have created, alongside the built-in *Birth* type, a custom *Alt-birth* type.

By adding the details of your preferred record to the *Birth* it will always be shown first as the birth event.

By adding the details of your other records to the *Alt-birth* event(s), these display in the individual's timeline according to their date.  But they are not selected when sorting/searching/displaying a family's *Birth*s.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of an explicit "preferred" setting, but I noticed that the first event of a given type seems to be displayed in contexts where it is required  (e.g. the tree view). Maybe this can help you, but alas, this would help only a little bit when you (or someone) else looks at a specific person and tries to figure out which of the events is the "right" one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a different "Role" for the other "Birth" events.

The preferred should still use the default (which is "Primary") for the role. You could use a custom type of role (such as "Unproven", "Disproven" or "Questionable") for the other Birth events.

Only the event with the Role as "Primary" and 1st in the list of Events will be considered as the Birth Date.

Since Baptism and Christening are "Fallback" events for Births, multiple instances of those event types follow the same pattern.